# Node.js Parse Error on Http request

Tags: parsing, node.js, request

I have a very simple request, but warn me `Parse Error`:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

var opts = {
    host: 'www.appletreebooks.com',
    path: 'www.appletreebooks.com/appIndex.php?c=eshop&m=get_hot_new_book_list&per_page=1&devid=c4c8874d16d84cde8fc7b9037ad8e26465bd1560&uid=1&ln=sn',
}

var req = http.request(opts, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var data = ""
    res.on('data', function(d) {
        data += d;
    })

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(data);
    })
})

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

But the response me `Parse Error`

What's wrong with my code? How can I get the data correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `opts.path` should not include the hostname.

```
var opts = {
    host: 'www.appletreebooks.com',
    path: '/appIndex.php?c=eshop&m=get_hot_new_book_list&per_page=1&devid=c4c8874d16d84cde8fc7b9037ad8e26465bd1560&uid=1&ln=sn',
}
```